# Цельные словосочетания. Как отличить составное именное сказуемое от определения?

Tags: cинтаксис, цельное-выражение

Приведу примеры:
**Эта девушка высокого роста, человек большого ума.**

В этом предложении *высокого роста* — сказуемое, а во втором *большого ума* —определение. Почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Эта девушка высокого роста, человек большого ума.*
>
> В этом предложении *высокого роста* —  сказуемое, а во втором
>   *большого ума* —  определение...

Вы не правы. *Большого ума*  — часть второго сказуемого:  ***человек большого ума.***

Comment: Смотрите, я взял эту информацию с сайта licey(лицей). Там было написано, что определение может быть выражено цельным словосочетанием с качественной характеристикой предмета (черта, свойство, возраст, мера, количество, признак по положению в пространстве)

Comment: _Антон Логунов: Там было написано, что определение может быть выражено цельным словосочетанием..._ === Да, может. К примеру, в таком предложении: _Девушка **с мужским лицом** стояла у письменного стола._ Но не в нашем случае. У нас подлежащее -- _девушка_, сказуемые -- _высокого роста_ и _(человек) большого ума_. Слово _человек_ входит во второе сказуемое. В принципе, оно в этом предложении необязательно. См.: _Эта девушка высокого роста, большого ума._ А вот слова _большого ума_ выкинуть из предложения вряд ли получится.

Comment: Извините, что так много вопросов. Объясните пожалуйста как разграничить цельное словосочетание выраженное сис и определение . Буду благодарен)

Comment: К сожалению, сейчас не успею -- должен бежать на электричку. Скажу коротко: при подлежащем определение вычленить проще. К примеру: _Эта девушка **высокого роста** --  человек большого ума._ Здесь **высокого роста** -- определение при слове _девушка_; сказуемое -- _человек большого ума_. Определение обычно легко выкинуть из предложения. Со сказуемым же так поступить вряд ли возможно... Извините, бегу...

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Хотел бы потом, когда будет свободное время увидеть полное объяснение. Если вы, конечно, поможете)

Answer (score 0):

**Эта** девушка (была) высокого роста, человек большого ума.

*Девушка* ― подлежащее, ***высокого роста, человек*** ― именные части сказуемого, *большого ума* ― определение к *человек.*

Comment: Arina, интуитивно хочется поставить тире между подлежащим и сказуемым: Эта девушка — высокого роста, человек большого ума. Хотелось бы узнать Ваше мнение.

Comment: И Ваше, @slava1947!

Comment: Осложнение сказуемого способствует постановке тире.Так,  Розенталь рекомендуе  тире при наличии однородных сказуемых: Ритм суворовского училища — чёткий, быстрый, военный. http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92#pp92. О заданном примере трудно сказать, он мне кажется надуманным (с такими примерами вообще не имеет смысла работать) , к  тому же многое зависит от контекста. Постановку тире надо проверять по интонации: в этом случае делается пауза, которая логически выделяет подлежащее.  .